# Is the @Repeatable annotation not supported by Groovy?

Tags: groovy, annotations

I'm coding in Groovy and am having trouble with the Java 8 @Repeatable meta-annotation. I think I'm doing everything right, but it appears that Groovy is not recognizing @Repeatable.  Here's my sample code; I'm expecting the information from both annotations to get stored in MyAnnotationArray:

```
import java.lang.annotation.*

class MyClass 
{
   @MyAnnotation(value = "val1")
   @MyAnnotation(value = "val2")
   void annotatedMethod() 
   {
       println("annotated method called")
   }

   public static void main(String... args)
   {
      MyClass ob = new MyClass()
      ob.annotatedMethod()
      java.lang.reflect.Method m = ob.getClass().getMethod("annotatedMethod")
      List annos = m.getAnnotations()
      println("annos = $annos")
   }
}

@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Repeatable(MyAnnotationArray) 
public @interface MyAnnotation
{
    String value() default "val0";
}

public @interface MyAnnotationArray 
{
   MyAnnotation[] MyAnnotationArray()
}
```

What happens is that I get this error:

```
Caught: java.lang.annotation.AnnotationFormatError: Duplicate annotation for class: interface MyAnnotation: @MyAnnotation(value=val2)
java.lang.annotation.AnnotationFormatError: Duplicate annotation for class: interface MyAnnotation: @MyAnnotation(value=val2)
```

Which is exactly what I get if I leave out the @Repeatable meta-annotation.

The code works fine if I leave out one of the duplicate MyAnnotations; then there is no error, and I then can read the annotation value as expected.

Is it possible that Groovy doesn't support the @Repeatable meta-annotation?  I couldn't find any documentation that states this outright, though [this page](https://www.slideshare.net/SpringCentral/groovy-in-thelightofjava8) hints that maybe this is the case (scroll down to item 88).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Groovy has supported "repeatable" annotations for a long time even in Java 5 so long as retention policy was only SOURCE. This is what allows multiple @Grab statements for instance without the outer @Grapes container annotation. Being only retained in SOURCE makes them useful for AST transformations and within the Groovy compiler itself (and other source processors) but not really useful anywhere else. We don't currently support @Repeatable at all but plan to in a future version.

Answer (score 3):

### seems to be  not supported

i used `java 1.8` and `groovy 2.4.11`

after compiling and de-compilig the same code i got this:

java:

```
@MyAnnotationArray({@MyAnnotation("val1"), @MyAnnotation("val2")})
public void annotatedMethod()
{
  System.out.println("annotated method called");
}
```

groovy:

```
@MyAnnotation("val1")
@MyAnnotation("val2")
public void annotatedMethod()
{
  System.out.println("annotated method called");null;
}
```

so, as workaround in groovy use

```
//note the square brackets
@MyAnnotationArray( [@MyAnnotation("val1"), @MyAnnotation("val2")] )
public void annotatedMethod()
{
  System.out.println("annotated method called");
}
```

---

full script (because there were some errors in annotation declaration)

```
import java.lang.annotation.*

class MyClass 
{
   //@MyAnnotation(value = "val1")
   //@MyAnnotation(value = "val2")
    @MyAnnotationArray( [@MyAnnotation("val1"), @MyAnnotation("val2")] )
    public void annotatedMethod()
    {
      System.out.println("annotated method called");
    }
   public static void main(String... args)
   {
      MyClass ob = new MyClass()
      ob.annotatedMethod()
      java.lang.reflect.Method m = ob.getClass().getMethod("annotatedMethod")
      List annos = m.getAnnotations()
      println("annos = $annos")
   }
}

@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Repeatable(MyAnnotationArray) 
public @interface MyAnnotation
{
    String value() default "val0";
}

@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface MyAnnotationArray 
{
   MyAnnotation[] value()
}
```

also tried against `groovy 3.0.0-SNAPSHOT` - the result is the same as for `2.4.11`